# React useRef returning null after running a useEffect to fill the initial state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-ref

I am attempting to hook my custom component to a ref using react's useRef in order to use html2canvas and render the element to a canvas.

```
const dataLetters = {
  headers: [
    'A',
    'B',
    'C',
    'D',
    'E',
    'F',
    'G'
  ],
  rows: [
    ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
  ]
};

export default function LettersPage() {
  // refs
  const LettersTableRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('letter ref');
    console.log(LettersTableRef.current); // same result when logging LettersTableRef
  }, [LettersTableRef]);

  return (
    <Page>
      <CustomizedTable ref={LettersTableRef} data={dataLetters } />
    </Page>
  );
}
```

However, this code when I run it, the console logs null after logging "letter ref". The CustomizedTable simply takes the data and builds rows and a header given the information - nothing fancier.

I am new to React and javascript. I have read I can in javascript give an element an id - I don't know how to do that in a react context, and am trying to stick to the practice of using React within React instead of plain js.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong!

-----Updated to add the code for CustomizeTable----

```
import Table from '@mui/material/Table';
import TableBody from '@mui/material/TableBody';
import TableCell, { tableCellClasses } from '@mui/material/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@mui/material/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@mui/material/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@mui/material/TableRow';

export default function CustomizedTables({ data, id }) {
  return (
    <TableContainer>
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            {data.headers.map((header) => (
              <TableCell>{header}</TableCell>
            ))}
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {data.rows.map((row) => (
            <TableRow>
              {row.map((datum) => (
                <TableCell>{datum}</TableCell>
              ))}
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser's console if there are any warnings? And can you post the `CustomizedTable` component?

Comment: Browser returns no errors - posting the CustomizedTable component now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check again on your browser's console. There should be some errors regarding `ref` and `each child in a list should have a unique key...`

Using `refs` is an advanced topic in React and you basically get a pointer to an object. This will work with references to class-components or HTML-elements but is not directly working with function components. For this you have to use `forwardRef` to wrap your function component inside.

I've fixed your code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-dew-u2bm9?file=/src/CustomizedTable.jsx

With `forwardRef` you can set the reference to any child element so the outer component can directly access it with `useRef`. There are some other ways to get methods as reference with `useImperativeHandle` but this will be even more advanced.

```js
const CustomizedTables = forwardRef(({ data, id }, ref) => (
    <TableContainer ref={ref}>
      ....
    </TableContainer>
));
```

I can strongly recommend the official documentation on this topic: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html

Comment: I am implementing this now - thank you for the detailed response. Would you happen to know if useRef as the pointer works like document.getElementById such that you can pass the pointer into html2canvas and produce a canvas version of the element?

Comment: When used like in the example the reference can be treated as a HTML-element the same as with `document.getElementById()`. So any "native" method like `getBoundingClientRect` are available.

Comment: The above solved my issue. I apologize for not knowing the useRef better - I am new to React. If I might bother you with one more question - I am attempting to use html2canvas, and I retreive this error:Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element is not attached to a Document after  html2canvas(ref).then((canvas) => {
      const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('img/png');
    });
which results in 
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element is not attached to a Document and Could not get the stack frames of error: TypeError: r is null

Is this a problem with useRef or with the html2canvas library?

Comment: You can create a canvas element and use `useRef` again and provide this reference to the `html2canvas` options.